# REGEX to MATCH a given PREFIX and SUFFIX

Tags: java, regex, match

I have strings composed of:

- Prefix + Suffix (may contain spaces between them)
- Prefix is **ALFA** (variable in length, upper or lower case, may not be present)
- Suffix is **NUMERIC** (variable in length, may contain spaces)

I need a REGEX to MATCH a given (**variable**) PREFIX and SUFFIX

**Examples** (prefix=ABCD, suffix=123456789):

```
String to match (several possible combinations):  
ABCD123456789  
abcd123456789  
ABCD 123456789  
abcd 123456789  
ABCD 123 456 789  
abcd 123 456 789  
123456789  
123 456 789  

String matches
+--------+-------------------+-------+  
| PREFIX |      SUFFIX       | MATCH |  
+--------+-------------------+-------+  
|        | 123456789         | YES   |  
|        | 123 456 789       | YES   |  
|        | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | YES   |  
| ABCD   | 123 456 789       | YES   |  
| ABCD   | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | YES   |  
+--------+-------------------+-------+  
|        | 12345678          | NO    |  
|        | 123 456 7890      | NO    |  
| ABCD   | 12345678          | NO    |  
| ABCD   | 123 456 7890      | NO    |  
|        | 123456789 ABCD    | NO    |  
| AB     | 123456789         | NO    |  
+--------+-------------------+-------+
```

**In other words**:
- Prefix must MATCH if present (case insensitive) and must be IGNORED if not present
- Suffix must MATCH (spaces must be IGNORED!)

**Equivalent JAVA code** would be:

```
//remove prefix (case insensitive)
STRING.substring(STRING.toUpperCase().startsWith(PREFIX) ? PREFIX.length() : 0).
//remove spaces
replace(" ","").
//match
equals(SUFFIX);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like the prefix is 4 letters and the suffix 9 digits?

Comment: Sorry! They can be variable in length... i will update the question.

Comment: Maybe you could strip out any white space first, then use `(prefix|PREFIX)?suffix`

Comment: Then why does `123 456 7890` fail?

Comment: @DavidFaber because in the example the suffix to match is 123456789, and should not match 1234567890

Comment: @jbaums, yes, i CAN strip out the spaces and then MATCH the resulting string, but i'm very limited to what i can do, because the string to match is a database field.

Comment: ^(ABCD)?\s*(1\s*2\s*3\s*4\s*5\s*6\s*7\s*8\s*9([\S]*)) That's what I got, works how you want it, if the 3rd capture group has something inside, the suffix is wrong, it will still match, but just create an if for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all spaces in/around the numeric suffix first:

```
str.replaceAll(" (?=[\\d ]*$)", "").matches("(?i)(ABCD)?123456789")
```

Matches all your test cases (and doesn't match your non-matches).

Comment: It works in java, but when used inside a query, it's transformed into "(ABCD)?123456789". Any idea why?? :-\

Comment: I tested it in http://www.regexr.com/ and i get "Invalid target for quantifier" in the first ?

Comment: The regex "(ABCD)?123456789" should be enough (works fine in java code), so i believe the problem has nothing to do with the regex itself, but with the query engine.

Comment: @marc that's because regexr doesn't understand in-line flags, like `(?i)` (ignore case). You must use the `i` flag at the end after a slash

Answer (score 0):

I know your question has a Java tag but I'm not familiar with Java. Since Java and JavaScript have some similarities, here is a JavaScript implementation to get ideas from.

```js
var rows = [{
    prefix: null,
    suffix: '123456789',
    assert: true
}, {
    prefix: null,
    suffix: '1123 456 789',
    assert: true
}, {
    prefix: null,
    suffix: '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9',
    assert: true
}, {
    prefix: 'ABCD',
    suffix: '123 456 789',
    assert: true
}, {
    prefix: 'ABCD',
    suffix: '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9',
    assert: true
},
{
    prefix: null,
    suffix: '12345678',
    assert: false
}, {
    prefix: null,
    suffix: '123 456 7890',
    assert: false
}, {
    prefix: 'ABCD',
    suffix: '12345678',
    assert: false
}, {
    prefix: 'ABCD',
    suffix: '123 456 7890',
    assert: false
}, {
    prefix: null,
    suffix: '123456789 ABCD',
    assert: false
}, {
    prefix: 'AB',
    suffix: '123456789',
    assert: false
}];

var PREFIX = 'ABCD';
var SUFFIX = '123456789';

var separator = '_';

var regex = new RegExp('^(' + PREFIX.toLowerCase() + ')?' + separator + '.*' + SUFFIX.replace(/\s+/g, '') + '$', 'g');

document.write('<pre>generated regex: ' + regex + '</pre>');

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    regex.lastIndex = 0;
    var item = rows[i];
    var pre = (item.prefix || '').toLowerCase();
    var suf = item.suffix.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    
    var subject = pre + separator + suf;
    
    var result = regex.test(subject);
    
    document.write('<pre class="' + ((result === item.assert) ? 'success' : 'fail') + '">' + pre + ' ' + suf + ', expected: ' + item.assert + ', result: ' + result + '</pre>');

}
```

```css
pre { padding: 5px; }
.success { border: 1px solid green; }
.fail { border: 1px solid red; }
```